# C++ lnk2019 and lnk 2020 yes it's in the right format

Tags: c++, css, fatal-error, lnk2019

Here's my code and the errors I'm receiving - any help would be appreciated.

There's something wrong with `getNextAcountNumber`. I have tried to assign the value of account ID but it has not worked since it is a private member.

> Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: int __thiscall Account::getNextAccountNumber(void)const " (?getNextAccountNumber@Account@@ABEHXZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Account::Account(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >,double)" (??0Account@@QAE@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@N@Z)  H:\programming\AccountClass\AccountClass.obj    AccountClass
>
> H:\programming\AccountClass\Debug\AccountClass.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

```css
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include "Account.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 Account  acct01;
 Account  acct02("Harold M. Ferguson", 2000);
 Account  acct03("Elise Janet Simmons", 3500);
 Account  acct04("James Holder", 0);

 cout << endl << "Account information - initial" << endl;
 acct01.displayAccountInfo();  // show account information - initial values
 acct02.displayAccountInfo();
 acct03.displayAccountInfo();
 acct04.displayAccountInfo();

 acct01.setAccountHolder("Mary A. Tarleton");
 acct01.setBalance(542.39);
 acct04.setAccountHolder("James Ellis Holder");
 acct04.setBalance(1990.75);

 cout << endl << "Account information after changes" << endl;
 acct01.displayAccountInfo();  // show account information after changes
 acct02.displayAccountInfo();
 acct03.displayAccountInfo();
 acct04.displayAccountInfo();

 acct01.depositAmount(455);   // make deposits
 acct02.depositAmount(-19.95);  // negative deposit not allowed - set to zero
 acct03.depositAmount(4365.27);
 acct04.depositAmount(95.63);

 cout << endl << "Account information after deposits" << endl;
 acct01.displayAccountInfo();  // show account information after deposits
 acct02.displayAccountInfo();
 acct03.displayAccountInfo();
 acct04.displayAccountInfo();

 acct01.withdrawAmount(37.39);
 acct02.withdrawAmount(-475.25);  // withdrawal may be positive or negative (absolute value)
 acct03.withdrawAmount(0.25);
 acct04.withdrawAmount(50.00);

 cout << endl << "Account information after withdrawals" << endl;
 acct01.displayAccountInfo();  // show account information after withdrawals
 acct02.displayAccountInfo();
 acct03.displayAccountInfo();
 acct04.displayAccountInfo();

 cout << endl;
 system("pause");
 return 0;
}
```

```css
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "Account.h"
#include <string>


using namespace std;

  

Account::Account()
{

 accountID = getNextAccountNumber();
 accountHolder = "no name";
 balance = 0;
}

Account::Account(string name, double amount)
{

 accountID = getNextAccountNumber();
 accountHolder = name;
 balance = amount;
 
}



int  Account::getAccountID()  const
{

 return accountID;
}
string Account::getAccountHolder() const
{
 return accountHolder;
}
double Account::getBalance()  const
{
 return balance;
}

void Account::setAccountHolder(string name)
{
 accountHolder = name;
}
void Account::setBalance(double amt)
{
 amt = balance;
}
void Account::depositAmount(double amt)
{
 if (amt > 0)
 {
  balance = +amt;
 }
 else;
 {
  balance = balance;
 }
}
void Account::withdrawAmount(double amt)
{
 balance = balance - amt;
}

void Account::displayAccountInfo() const
{
 cout << accountID << accountHolder << balance;
}
```

```css
#ifndef ACCOUNT_H
#define ACCOUNT_H

#include <string>

using namespace std;

static int accountNumber = 100000;   // starting value for account#

class Account
{
public:
 Account();        // default constructor
 Account(string name, double amount); // constructor with two parameters

 int  getAccountID()  const;  // ACCESSOR member functions
 string getAccountHolder() const;  // return name of account holder
 double getBalance()  const;  // return account balance

 void setAccountHolder(string name); // MUTATOR member functions
 void setBalance(double amt);   // assign amount to balance
 void depositAmount(double amt);  // add amount to balance
 void withdrawAmount(double amt);  // subtract absolute value of amount from balance
 // HELPER member functions
 void displayAccountInfo() const; // display account information

private:
 int  getNextAccountNumber() const; // get next account# (pre-increment account number)
 // private DATA members
 int  accountID;      // account# identifier
 string accountHolder;     // name of account holder
 double balance;      // account balance
};


// accountID = ++accountNumber    
#endif
```

Comment: The error is telling you that you forgot to write the definition for `Account::getNextAccountNumber`.

Comment: Where did you implement `getNextAcccountNumber`?

Comment: Is all of this code relevant to the problem? Please see this post about [minimum, complete, verifiable examples](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: yes all code is relevant and i can figure out how or where to write getAccountNumber considering it is a private member, thanks for the fast response.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not related to the function being private - it is being called by the constructor(s), which have access to the private members of the class.

Both @DrewDormann and @PaulMcKenzie seem correct in the comments - you have (at least listed) no implementation for `Account::getNextAccountNumber()`

This should likely be in the second code snippet you have posted (likely `Account.cpp`, or similar)

Consider adding something like

```
int Account::getNextAccountNumber()
{
    return accountNumber++;
}
```

However, this would seem in nature to be a function independent of anything even remotely related to any individual given `Account`, so consider making it a freestanding function. (i.e. not a member of the `Account` class)

Then you'd just have

```
int getNextAccountNumber()
{
    return accountNumber++;
}
```

but in that case, you'd have to modify the header (perhaps `Account.h`?) to remove the member function. Otherwise, you'll still get the linker error you're currently hitting.

Edit:  The function is declared as `const`, so you need the `const` specifier.

```
int Account::getNextAccountNumber() const
{
    return accountNumber++;
}
```

Comment: Chris I have tried that and my error message for that was:

Comment: 3 IntelliSense: declaration is incompatible with "int Account::getNextAccountNumber() const" (declared at line 28 of "h:\programming\accountclass\Account.h") h:\programming\AccountClass\AccountClass.cpp 28 14 AccountClass

Comment: I will try to make it an independent function but the code how it is written now was what was given to me to use and work around.

Comment: @walvering The function is missing the `const` specifier.  Second, don't post Intellisense errors -- they are **not** compiler errors.

Comment: Seems a bit twisted labelling it `const` though... Sure, it doesn't change the object referenced by `this`, but it clearly is meant to change global state. I guess just a reason it might be better as a non-member function.